# Moving ball at an Angle

Tags: java, graphics, awt

I am a newbie and trying to move a ball at a slope. Here is the code where I am giving coordinates (100,300,300,600) to move the ball in a slope but it's getting away from the the slope line. Here's the code: -

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class AgentMotion extends JPanel implements Runnable
{
    Color color = Color.red;
    int   dia   = 0;
    long  delay = 40;
    private double x;
    private double y;
    private double x1;
    private double y1;
    private int dx = 1;
    private int dy = 1;
    private int dv = 1;
    private double direction;
    double a;
    double b;
    double a1;
    double b1;


    public void abc(double x, double y, double x2, double y2) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.x1 = x2;
        this.y1 = y2;
        this.direction=Math.toRadians(Math.atan2(x1-x,y1-y));
        System.out.println("segfewg"+direction);
        this.a = x;
        this.b = y;
        this.a1 = x1;
        this.b1 = y1;
    }



    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                            RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g.setColor(color);
        //int x=100;
        //int y=200;
        int x3=(int)this.x;
        int y3=(int)this.y;
        g.fillOval(x3,y3,5,5);   // adds color to circle
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g2.drawOval(x3,y3,5,5);   // draws circle
        g2.drawLine(100, 300, 300, 600);
    }

    public void run() {

        if(direction<0)
        {
            System.out.println("refregreg");
            while(dy!=0) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(delay);
                } catch(InterruptedException e) {
                    System.out.println("interrupted");
                }
                move2();

                repaint();

                move();
                repaint();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            while(dx!=0) {

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(delay);
                } catch(InterruptedException e) {
                    System.out.println("interrupted");
                }
                move2();

                repaint();

                move();
                repaint();
            }


        }


    }


    public void move() {


        if(direction>0)
        {
            if(x + dv*Math.cos(direction) <a ||x  + dia + dv * Math.cos(direction) >b) {
                dx *= 0;
                color = getColor();

            }

            x += dx;
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println(x  + dia + dv * Math.cos(direction));
            if(x  + dia + dv * Math.cos(direction) >b) {
                dx *= 0;
                color = getColor();

            }

            x -= dx;

        }
    }


    public void move2() {

        if(direction>0)
        {
            if(dv * Math.sin(direction) + y <a1 || dv * Math.sin(direction) + dia + y > b1) {

                dy *= 0;
                color = getColor();
            }
            y += dy;
        }
        else
        {

            System.out.println(dv * Math.sin(direction) + dia + y);
            if(dv * Math.sin(direction) + y <a1 || dv * Math.sin(direction) + dia + y < b1) {


                dy *= 0;
                color = getColor();
            }
            y -= dy;
        }

    }



    public Color getColor() {
        int rval = (int)Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
        int gval = (int)Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
        int bval = (int)Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
        return new Color(rval, gval, bval);
    }

    public void start() {
        while(dx==0) {
            try {
                System.out.println("jiuj");
                Thread.sleep(25);
            } catch(InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("dwdwdwd");
            }
        }
        Thread thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.setPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY);
        thread.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: too much unrelated and uncommented code to look at ... I am no JAVA coder but aren't atan2 already in radians (check the reference for that function)? also check if all fractional variables are float or double and not int ... also too many variables for this task I think ...

Comment: Why dx *= 0?  That simplifies to dx = 0.

Answer (score 0):

A few suggestions

1. dx and dy should be double
2. atan is overkill as @Spektre says.  What you want is much more simple to calculate direction.

   `this.direction = (y2 - y) / (x2 - x)`
3. If we give (100,300,300,600) as the arguments to abc (which would presumably be a constructor for this class), the slope is 1.5.  Therefore we could say:

   `dx = 1.0
   dy = 1.5`

and this would keep on the line perfectly.  For the general case where you want to change the begin and the end point, you have to calculate the ratio.  So you could set either dx or dy to 1.0 and then set the other one so that the ratio is maintained.  Something like the following mathematical pseudocode:

- dx = (x2 - x) / minimum(x2-x, y2-y)
- dy = (y2 - y) / minimum(x2-x, y2-y)